# showing DoughnutChart in Slices using aChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to know how can I show my DoughnutChart created in aChartEngine library in slices as figure below. I spend an hour in finding a way of doing that but failed.
[image]

Comment: You could use a pie chart instead of the doughtnut chart because the pie chart supports slice highlighting.

Comment: Thank you Dan for providing us such great library.DoughnutChart will look cool when sliced and I hope you provide this feature in future updates ,for now I will use Pie Chart. Thanks again